# How to end JavaFX threads and terminating them when called by Platform.runLater()?

Tags: java, multithreading, javafx

I have a program which is not in JavaFX application thread, and I want to call some JavaFX application in it in order to do something for me.
Here is my code:

```
public void extractImages(Document document) {
        ImageExtractor_HTML_Data.getInstance().documentId = document.getId();
        if (!ImageExtractor_HTML_Data.getInstance().started)
            new JFXPanel();
        ImageExtractor_HTML_Data.getInstance().started = true;
        Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
            ImageExtractor_HTML_Browser browser = new ImageExtractor_HTML_Browser();

            @Override
            public void run() {
                browser.start(new Stage());
            }
        });

        synchronized (ImageExtractor_HTML_Data.getInstance()) {
            try {
                ImageExtractor_HTML_Data.getInstance().wait();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

And my Browser class is:

```
public class ImageExtractor_HTML_Browser extends Application {
    private Scene scene;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {

        /* Some code */

        stage.setTitle("Web View");
        Browser browser = new Browser(htmlFile, stage);
        scene = new Scene(browser, 750, 500, Color.web("#666970"));
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
        browser.imageExtractor(new ImageHandler_DB_HTML(document));
    }
```

And my imageExtractor method is:

```
public void imageExtractor(final ImageHandler handler) {
        webEngine.getLoadWorker().stateProperty()
                .addListener(new ChangeListener<Worker.State>() {
                    @Override
                    public void changed(
                            @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes") ObservableValue observableValue,
                            Worker.State state, Worker.State newState) {
                        if (newState.equals(Worker.State.SUCCEEDED)) {
                            /* Some code which extract some data */
                            synchronized (ImageExtractor_HTML_Data
                                    .getInstance()) {
                                ImageExtractor_HTML_Data.getInstance().notify();
                            }
                            stage.close();
                            Platform.exit();
                            return;
                        }
                    }
                });
    }
```

In imageExtractor method I want to wait until my HTML file load completly and then I want to do something, so I use WebEngine.getLoadWorker.etc.
My problem is that after run of this code, my JavaFX threads didn't finish so my program didn't end.
Although, I don't want to use System.exit(0) because my program runs in the middle of a project which runs via tomcat and if I use System.exit(0), whole project comes down which is not good at all!

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I understand the problem. it is because of the 'new JFXPanel()' which I called in order to initialize the JavaFX toolkit. I call it in another place and my code got correct!
it's the the corrected version:

```
public void extractImages(Document document) {
        ImageExtractor_HTML_Data.getInstance().documentId = document.getId();

        Thread javaFxThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new JFXPanel();
                Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
                    ImageExtractor_HTML_Browser browser = new ImageExtractor_HTML_Browser();

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        browser.start(new Stage());
                    }
                });
            }
        });
        javaFxThread.setDaemon(true);
        javaFxThread.start();

        synchronized (ImageExtractor_HTML_Data.getInstance()) {
            try {
                ImageExtractor_HTML_Data.getInstance().wait();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```